# I Need Help Determining How to Return All Contents of a For Loop (and Not Just The Final Line)

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return

```
#Write a function called steps that takes one parameter
#that represents the number of 'steps' to print. It should
#then return a string that, when printed, shows output like
#the following:
```

I have been able to write the function, steps, that takes a parameter called number_steps, which represents the number of steps (which is between 1 and 9). Inside the function, I defined an empty string called nstep, and I wrote a for loop with iteration variable i that ranges from 1 to steps + 1 (in order to ensure it captured all steps). I then did a string concatenation inside the loop by making nstep equal to iteration variable - 1 times the tab character (converting that operation to a string) and adding it to the iteration variable times 3 (also converting that operation to a string). I did put a print statement to show the different values of nstep as the loop ran, and I returned the value at nstep at the end with the return statement being at the same level of indentation as for.

```
def steps(number_steps):
    nstep = ""
    for i in range(1, (number_steps + 1)):
        nstep = str((i-1) * "\t") + (str(i) * 3)
        print(nstep)
    return nstep
```

If the function does as it should, it will return a string that, when printed, shows output like
the following:

```
#print(steps(3))
111
    222
        333

#print(steps(6))
111
    222
        333
            444
                555
                    666
```

However, in my case, I get the below. I threw the print statement inside the for loop, and it does print out the lines like the test cases do when the loop is running. However, once the loop is done and the functions executes the return statement, it only shows the last line and ignores all the previous lines. What am I missing and how should I go about fixing?

```
    333
                666
```

Comment: Instead of `nstep =`, try `nstep +=`, to append to the string on each iteration. You'll also need to append a newline (`'\n'`) on every step.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I completely forgot about += and great point about '\n', that fixed the code and got it working, thank you!